# SQL Aggregate Function and Retain all Rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL statement which will return the count of a concatenation of multiple columns but then retain all rows in the original table.

For instance, I have a table listing a combination of Customers and Items.  There may be multiple lines for a specific Customer + Item combination.  I would like to have a column showing me the count of the Customer + Item combination in the whole table on each row.

So if Customer1 + Item1 combination occurs 10 times in my table, I want this new column to show 10, but I still want the resulting table to have all 10 of the original rows.

Comment: Delete this question.  Then ask another question and provide sample data, desired results, and any attempt you have made to solve the problem.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: the SQL dialect alone would already help ...

Answer (score 0):

what about using a subquery...

in T-SQL (since you didn't specify a dialect...) that could look like this:

```
select 
  customer, 
  item, 
  (
    select 
      count(*) 
    from table i 
    where 
      i.customer = o.customer and i.item = o.item
  ) 
from table o
```